# Dynamically generated images: nginx + php-fpm

Tags: nginx, image-generation

I'd like to use

```
location /images/ {
    try_files $uri @generateImage;
}

location @generateImage {
    # pass to backend php-fpm
}
```

for image generation. But it in this case I have to take care of php-fpm load at the first generation of some image (we have huge amount of requests, it's some sort of banner exchange) . Is it way to configure nginx to wait processing of the first php-fpm call to the same location?

Answer (score 0):

Usually real time processing like this is really a bad idea, if you get a high traffic at some point it will effect your system badly, is there a way you could queue those images for processing then handle them by a cron job?

And if you still want to do it your way i would suggest making the php script issue a redirect response when it's done, given that you know for sure that it wont take a long time to generate that image, or make it reply with the image data directly after giving the correct `content-type` to the browser.

Comment: It means that first request wouldn't get image, so queue is not perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

These two requirements bite each other. On one hand your server cannot handle spawning php processes, while serving a large amount of static files, on the other hand you want dynamic content in real-time. The obvious answer is to split the two over different machines. Your generate block is then a proxy config that passes the request to a dedicated image generation machine (or two, three,....). The script on the generator should return the result as well as scribe it to disk. Cron and rsync can handle synchronization to the static content servers.
If you need help with your config, make a new post with specific questions.